# I need to assign multiple tuples to one list and write a csv file

Tags: python, csv

I want to write a program that finds the number of all emails I received and also the list of people who have emailed I and saves it in a text and CSV file that contains two columns: the person who sent the email and the time of the email.

My problem is that the output of the program gives a lot of tuples
And I can't convert this output to CSV file including two columns email and time. In order to write the CSV file, I need to put all the tuples in one list

```
with open('../data/mbox-short.txt', 'r') as file_h:
    count = 0
    for line in file_h:
        if line.startswith('From '):
            word_list = line.split()
            Email = word_list[1:2]
            Hour = word_list[5:6]
            Email_Hour = tuple(Email + Hour)
            count = count +1
            print(Email_Hour)
    print(f'count = {count}')
```

Comment: Then create a list before the loop and append the tuple to the list.

Comment: You also need to open the file for writing (tip: you don't even need to store all the tuples into a list).

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest maybe something along the lines of this:

```py
import csv
with open('../data/mboxoutput.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile)
    rows = []
    with open('../data/mbox-short.txt', 'r') as file_h:

        for line in file_h:
            if line.startswith('From '):
                word_list = line.split()
                rows.append([word_list[1:2], word_list[5:6]])

        print(f'count = {len(rows)}')
        csvwriter.writerows(rows)
```

The key difference here is just bringing the rows out into a single list of lists, which is usable by the .writerows() method of the CSV module. [Docs here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.writerows)

This is a little pasted together, you could have some fun with list comprehension here also to save you some lines, or just as a fun syntax-sugar exercise:

```py
import csv
with open('../data/mboxoutput.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile)
    rows = [[[word_list[1:2], word_list[5:6] for word_list in line]] for line in open('../data/mbox-short.txt', 'r').readlines() if line.startswith('From ')]

    print(f'count = {len(rows)}')
    csvwriter.writerows(rows)
```

Comment: You could also do `csvwriter.writerow([word_list[1:2], word_list[5:6]])` on each iteration of the loop, then there's no need to build up the `rows` list. That's more memory-efficient for larger files.